# parsing json with different amounts of string properties

Tags: javascript, json

Could anyone tell me how I would go about displaying the following json in html? The problem I am facing is that the sections have different string fields - for example the first only has 3 (name, quantity and card) and the next has 4. I'm going to write titles beside each one (The name: One, Quantity: 50 etc) but I don't want to display the title if the string field does not exist

```
  {
        "products": [
            {
                "name": "One",
                "quantity": 50,
                "type": "card"
            },

             {
                "name": "Two",
                "thumbnail": "us.jpg",
                "quantity": 50,
                "type": "card"
            },
            {
                "name": "Three",
                "thumbnail": "thumb.jpg",

            }
        ]
    }
```

Any  ideas or advice?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you actually want to do with given data - however, you can walk through the object by using `for`, as:

```
var json = {a: 5, b: 6, c: "aaa"}

for (var index in json)
    console.log(index+" "+json[index]);
```

Comment: Thank you  - but how would I do this if I wanted to display using different titles? So in your example, instead of say a : 5 being printed, I would print "Number : 5" So my title would replace the index

Comment: That's where `depends on what you actually want to do` kicks in. You'd need to place some conditions depending upon the value of the index. Like for example: `typeof json[index] == "number" ? "Number" : index`

Comment: Ok thanks again, I dont actually want to check what the type is. What I want to do is if the index is 'name' as per my code above - then I want to display some thing like "The name : One" - does that make sense?

Comment: Like this? `index == "name" ? "The name" : index`

Answer (score 1):

Couple of loops 'ought to do the trick:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.products.length; i++) {
    for (var key in data.products[i]) {
        //looping keys, rather than log, append to HTML somewhere
        console.log(key + ":" + data.products[i][key]); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - but what if I want to set my own names where the index is being set - for example, if the index name is 'quantity' , I'd like to replace the name as 'Amount' so it would display 'Amount : 50' - does that make sense?